# How to test REST controller with custom validation

Tags: java, rest, validation, junit

I test REST controller with postman, it works great. But when I run jUnit tests it fails on POST method.
Validator:

```
public class UniqueAuditoriumConstraintValidator implements ConstraintValidator<UniqueAuditorium, AuditoriumDto> {

    @Autowired
    private AuditoriumService auditoriumService;

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(AuditoriumDto auditoriumDto, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        Auditorium auditorium = auditoriumService.findByNumberAndBuildingId(auditoriumDto.getNumber(),
                auditoriumDto.getBuildingId());
        if (auditorium != null && auditorium.getNumber() == auditoriumDto.getNumber()
                && auditorium.getBuilding().getId() == auditoriumDto.getBuildingId()
                && auditorium.getId() != auditoriumDto.getId()) {
            context.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
            context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate("{com.rumakin.universityschedule.validation.unique.auditorium}")
                    .addPropertyNode("number").addConstraintViolation();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
}
}
```

Service part:

```
public Auditorium findByNumberAndBuildingId(int number, int buildingId) {
        logger.debug("findByNumberAndBuildingId() {},{}.", number, buildingId);
        Auditorium auditorium = Optional.ofNullable(auditoriumDao.findByNumberAndBuildingId(number, buildingId)).orElse(new Auditorium());
        logger.trace("foundByNumberAndBuildingId {},{} result {}.", number, buildingId, auditorium);
        return auditorium;
    }
```

REST controller:

```
@RestController
@Validated
@RequestMapping("/api/auditoriums")
public class AuditoriumRestController {

    private AuditoriumService auditoriumService;
    private final ModelMapper modelMapper;
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuditoriumRestController.class);

    @Autowired
    public AuditoriumRestController(AuditoriumService auditoriumService, ModelMapper modelMapper) {
        this.auditoriumService = auditoriumService;
        this.modelMapper = modelMapper;
    }
@PostMapping("")
    public ResponseEntity<AuditoriumDto> add(@Valid @RequestBody AuditoriumDto auditoriumDto) {
        Auditorium auditorium = auditoriumService.add(convertToEntity(auditoriumDto));
        return new ResponseEntity<>(convertToDto(auditorium), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

and test:

```
@WebMvcTest(AuditoriumRestController.class)
class AuditoriumRestControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    private final ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();

    @MockBean
    private AuditoriumService mockAuditoriumService;

   @Test
    public void addShouldAddEntityToDBAndReturnItWithIdWhenDBCallFine() throws Exception {
        Building building = new Building(1, "Main", "Khimki");
        Auditorium auditorium = new Auditorium(7, 8, building);
        AuditoriumDto auditoriumDto = convertToDto(auditorium);
        Auditorium auditoriumFromDb = new Auditorium(11, 7, 8, building);
        AuditoriumDto auditoriumDtoFromDb = convertToDto(auditoriumFromDb);
        Mockito.when(mockAuditoriumService.findByNumberAndBuildingId(Mockito.anyInt(), Mockito.anyInt()))
                .thenThrow(ResourceNotFoundException.class);
        Mockito.when(mockAuditoriumService.add(auditorium)).thenReturn(auditoriumFromDb);
        mockMvc.perform(post("/api/auditoriums").content(convertToJson(auditoriumDto)).contentType(APPLICATION_JSON)
                .accept(APPLICATION_JSON)).andExpect(status().isCreated()).andExpect(result -> is(auditoriumDtoFromDb));
    }

    @Test
    public void updateShouldUpdateEntryInDBAndReturnItWhenDBCallFine() throws Exception {
        Building building = new Building(1, "Main", "Khimki");
        Auditorium auditorium = new Auditorium(12, 8, 9, building);
        AuditoriumDto auditoriumDto = convertToDto(auditorium);
        Mockito.when(mockAuditoriumService.update(auditorium)).thenReturn(auditorium);
        Mockito.when(mockAuditoriumService.findByNumberAndBuildingId(anyInt(), anyInt()))
                .thenThrow(ResourceNotFoundException.class);
        mockMvc.perform(put("/api/auditoriums").content(convertToJson(auditoriumDto)).contentType(APPLICATION_JSON)
                .accept(APPLICATION_JSON)).andExpect(status().isOk()).andExpect(result -> is(auditoriumDto));
    }
```

Well, it fails with:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000028: Unexpected exception during isValid call.
```

it means NPE appears when service methods findByNumberAndBuildingId was called and mock return null or different Entity. If mock return same entity as input it works correct- return validation constraint.
I tried to mock validator and return Boolean.TRUE but nothing changed.
How to fix and or deactivate validation only for tests?

Comment: I update fields of Test class and now find, getAll and delete tests passed. But I have still problem with add and update. Result of tests - 500 status instead of 200/201. I even use logging in validation and find out, that result is "true", passed! But still javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000028: Unexpected exception during isValid call.

Comment: What are you doing to run the isValid code? I have a very similar setup to your, if not almost identical, but when running a perform it goes directly to the controller code skipping my custom validator which works well when making calls from postman. I have seen very convoluted solutions about ConstraintValidatorFactories, but you seem to be running your isValid without any specific setup